# Running MapReduce Code on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a doubt.

If I run a MapReduce code via eclipse in Master Node , does that code run using the resources of entire cluster or will it run locally only on Master machine ?

Answer (score 0):

"Entire cluster".

This depends on configuration and yarn manager(Can see log and status on yarn)